# How to search word in linux terminal

Tags: linux, shell, terminal, command

I have used terminal window for long time, There is a lot of stdout prints. Here I need command to search some word in history of linux terminal(stdout). like find option in text document.

Comment: Do you need to search through the commands you've executed, or do you need to search the output of those commands?

Comment: You could start a shell under `emacs` with `M-x shell`. Then you can use all the `emacs` abilities inside it (including searching with *Ctrl-S*, paren-matching, etc....).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To search through the commands you have executed run the following command

```
    history |grep 'your search word goes in here'
```

Comment: -1, the OP wants to search stdout, not their previously issued commands.

Comment: how come this is the accepted answer?

Answer (score 1):

Well, i use screen for running the linux terminal.

There you can just do ctrl + a, followed by either / or ? and then the string to search in the stdout.

```
 http://serverfault.com/questions/106388/screen-setup-tips

 Check out the link to learn about screen, will make your life simpler!! :-)
```

Answer (score 1):

In case you are using bash, you can also open the `.bash_history` file with any standard text editor and operate on it.